# How many fixed points can a function have?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

For dimension one, it is easy to think in samples of continuous functions $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ with one, two, three,... fixed points. Or even, infinitely fixed points (take the idendity map). 
But I am intereseted in the following result that one old teacher told me:

Theorem: For any given non-empty and closed subset $C\subseteq \overline{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,r)$, there exists a continuous function $f:\overline{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,r)\rightarrow\overline{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,r)$, where $\overline{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}(0,r)$ is the closed ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $0$, such that the set of fixed points of $f$ is exactly the set $C$.

Can anyone give me some idea or hint to prove it? My attempts have not worked sucessfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $C$ bounded?

Comment: Doesn’t $C$ have to be within the ball for this to make sense?

Comment: Yes, $C$ must be contained in the closed ball. I have already edited the post.

Comment: Ok so now $C$ is compact.

Comment: My first thoughts here are: have you tried picking an $r>0$, such that $C$ lies within the ball, then take $f$ which is the identity on $C$ and not the identity outside of $C$. Note that we don't need it to be differentiable. So this should be possible, right?

Comment: True, I forgot that. $C$ is compact.

Comment: That was my first thought. Take the identity on $C$ and extend it continuously on the closed ball. But how can I assure that I obtain a continuous map from the closed ball into the closed ball?

Comment: **Hint:** $\ d(x, C)\ $ is a continuous real-valued function on $\ \overline{B}_{\mathbb R^n}(\,0,r\,)\ $ which is strictly positive for $\ x\not\in C\ $.  Can you think of a way to displace each element $\ x\ $ in $\ \overline{B}_{\mathbb R^n}(\,0,r\,)\setminus C\ $ by something proportional to this amount while keeping it within $\ \overline{B}_{\mathbb R^n}(\,0,r\,)\ $?

Comment: Hint following up the suggestion in your deleted comment: **dividing** something by a number bigger than $1$ makes it smaller. This might help in keeping it inside a closed region.

Comment: And if you want $f$ to be differentiable too, maybe squaring something will help.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera While the initial idea is good, this has some issues: what if $0\not\in C$? Scaling won't work. You may think that you can scale relative to any point in $B$, but that only works in the interior of the ball.

Comment: The idea is to choose a point $\ x_0\ $ in $\ C\ $ and define $\ f(x)\ $ to be $\frac{x}{1+d(x,C)}+ \frac{d(x,C)\,x_0}{1+d(x,C)}\ $.  At the moment, I can't see why this doesn't work, although I must admit I haven't checked everything carefully.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+d(x,C)}+\frac{d(x,C)x_0}{1+d(x,C)}$ for all $x$ in the closed ball satisfies that is continuous, $x\in C$ iff $x$ is a fixed point of $f$ and the image of $f$ is contained in the closed ball. So it seems that your answer is correct! and also it seems that we can remove the hypothesis $C$  is closed, because it is not used, isn't it?

Comment: If $\ C\ $ isn't closed then $\ \partial C\setminus C\ $ will be non-empty and its elements will be fixed points of the function that aren't in $\ C\ $.

Comment: Following the idea of @timtfj, if we consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+d(x,C)^2}+\frac{d(x,C)^2x_0}{1+d(x,C)^2}$$ on the closed ball verifies that its image is contained into the closed ball, its fixed points are exactly the points in C and moreover it is differentiable

Comment: In general, the function $\ f(x) = \frac{x}{1+d(x,C)^2} + \frac{d(x,C)^2\,x_0}{1+d(x,C)^2}\ $ isn't differentiable everywhere.  For a specific example, take $\ n=1\ , r=2, C=\{-1,1\},$ and $\ x_0 = -1\ $.  Then $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{x}{1+(x+1)^2} -  \frac{(x+1)^2}{1+(x+1)^2} & \mathrm{\ for\ } x<0 \\ \frac{x}{1+(x-1)^2} -  \frac{(x-1)^2}{1+(x-1)^2}  & \mathrm{\ for\ } x\ge 0 &\ .\end{matrix}\right. $$ This is not differentiable at $\ x=0\ $ $(\ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = -\frac{1}{2},
\  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{3}{2}$ ).

Comment: What about assuming that C is also convex.  Then the ortogonal projection theorem gives a unique $\xi_x\in C$ for each $x$ in the closed ball s.t. $d(x,C)^2=\Vert x-\xi_x\Vert^2$ and putting this inside the function will give a differentiable one?

Comment: My guess is that this should work, but the proof doesn't appear to me be completely straightforward.  My attempted proof looked like it could only be made to work by proving that $\ \xi_x\ $ is differentiable, which is something I'm not aware of as being an already known theorem.